# Error in routing with id parameter, link works but displays no data

Tags: angularjs, express, mongoose, mean-stack, ngresource

I am having an issue with retrieving the stored data (within MongoDB) by way of an :id parameter. The link works and takes me to the specified url (./contests/1), but the data doesn't show up. When querying within the mongo CMD with (db.contests.find( {id:1} )) the correct object's data is displayed correctly.

### route/contest.js

```
router.route("/contests/:id")
  .get(function(req, res, next) {
     Contest.findOne({id: req.params.id}, function(err, contest) {
      if(err) {
        res.send(err);
      }
      res.json(contest);
  });
```

### service/contestService.js

```
  app.factory("contestService", ["$http", "$resource",
  function($http, $resource)
  {
    var o = {
      contests: []
    };

    function getAll() {
      return $http.get("/contests").then(function(res) {
        angular.copy(res.data, o.contests);
      });
    }

    function get(id) {
      return $resource('/contests/:id');
    }

    o.getAll = getAll;
    o.get = get;

    return o;
  }]);
})();
```

### controller/contestController.js

```
var app = angular.module("sportsApp.controllers.contest,["ui.router"]);

  app.config(["$stateProvider", function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("contest", {
      parent: "root",
      url: "/contests/:id",
      views: {
        "container@": {
          templateUrl: "partials/contests",
          controller: "ContestController"
        }
      }
    });
  }
]);

app.controller("ContestController", ["$scope","contestService", "$stateParams", function($scope, contestService, $stateParams) {
  var contest_id = $stateParams.id;
  $scope.contest = contestService.get({id: contest_id});
}]);
})();
```

### Contest Schema

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var ContestSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    id: Number,
    tags: String,
    matchups: [{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Matchup"
    }],
    usersWhoJoined: [{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User"
    }]
  });



mongoose.model("Contest", ContestSchema);
```

Any assistance or advice would be much appreciated due to the fact that I am learning as I go with the MEAN stack and have little to no experience with it.

---

I am looking to display the specific contest's matchups in which displays two teams and other variables. This is my json file that I mongoimported in order to create the object of the contests collection within MongoDB:

```
    {
    "id": 1,
    "tags": "NBA",
    "matchups": [{
        "matchupId": 1,
        "selectedTeam": "",
        "matchupWinner": "Atlanta",
        "nbaTeams": [{
            "team": "Portland",
            "logo": "stylesheets/nbalogos/Portland-Trail-Blazers-Logo.png"
        }, {
            "team": "Atlanta",
            "logo": "stylesheets/nbalogos/atl-hawks.png"
        }]
    }, {
        "matchupId": 2,
        "selectedTeam": "",
        "matchupWinner": "Dallas",
        "nbaTeams": [{
            "team": "Dallas",
            "logo": "stylesheets/nbalogos/Dallas-Mavericks.png"
        }, {
            "team": "Detroit",
            "logo": "stylesheets/nbalogos/DET.png"
        }]
    }, {
        "matchupId": 3,
        "selectedTeam": "",
        "matchupWinner": "Golden State",
        "nbaTeams": [{
            "team": "Golden State",
            "logo": "stylesheets/nbalogos/GSW.png"
        }, {
            "team": "Memphis",
            "logo": "stylesheets/nbalogos/Memphis-Grizzlies.png"
        }]
    }, {
        "matchupId": 4,
        "selectedTeam": "",
        "matchupWinner": "Oklahoma City",
        "nbaTeams": [{
            "team": "Oklahoma City",
            "logo": "stylesheets/nbalogos/OKC-Thunder.png"
        }, {
            "team": "Pheonix",
            "logo": "stylesheets/nbalogos/Pheonix-Suns.jpg"
        }]
    }, {
        "matchupId": 5,
        "selectedTeam": "",
        "matchupWinner": "Utah",
        "nbaTeams": [{
            "team": "Sacremento",
            "logo": "stylesheets/nbalogos/Sacremento-Kings.jpg"
        }, {
            "team": "Utah",
            "logo": "stylesheets/nbalogos/Utah-Jazz.jpg"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I want to create each contest in this format.

Comment: Not sure on the whole of your error, and this may not be related since you're seeing your error in Postman, but an Angular service/resource doesn't work like Express. You need to manually concat the id with your url, like: `return $resource('/contests/' + id);`.

Comment: I made the change to the code and unfortunately it was unrelated to the Postman error. But, it was beneficial to my future routes within the project. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Are you sure `Contest` is configured properly, and Mongo is running within Express?

Comment: Yes I am sure, I was wrong though. Your recommendation did get rid of the Postman error so thank you sooooo much for that. Now, another quick question, when I try to display any of the contest's information with the sytax, {{ contest.id }} or any other variable nothing is displayed. Still get an empty table. My professor requested that I upload my schema so I edited my post.

Comment: What type of variable is `contestService.get` expecting? What type of variable are you calling it with when you assign `$scope.contest`?

Comment: Please see the edit above, much easier to input the answers to your questions. Once again, thank you so very much my good sir. Your help and assistance is tremendously appreciated.

Comment: I appreciate your posting more code, but you need to be more explicit in what you've tried and exactly where your problem is. We can't do your assignment for you.

Comment: "I am looking to display the specific contest's matchups in which displays two teams and other variables. This is my json file that I mongoimported in order to create the object of the contests collection within MongoDB."

Comment: "when I try to display any of the contest's information with the sytax, {{ contest.id }} or any other variable nothing is displayed. Still get an empty table"

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what relevance the actual data has to this issue, so let's start with `$scope.contest`, since there seems to be a problem with the way you're accessing data.

```
// ContestController
$scope.contest = contestService.get({id: contest_id});
```

OK, so you're calling the `contestService.get` method with an object, let's say it's `{id: 2}`. Let's look at that method and call it with that object.

```
// contestService
function get(id) {
    return $resource('/contests/' + id);
}
```

If using our dummy data, if you call `get({id: 2})`, you now have an Angular resource at the URL `/contests/[object Object]` because your object [gets converted into a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString). Your method would work if called using the value at the `id` property of that object, like:

```
// ContestController
$scope.contest = contestService.get(contest_id);
```